# render Start Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'

Tags: javascript, express, discord.js

I'm tying to deploy my discord bot dashboard on render I get this error

```
Apr 12 11:42:20 PM  ==> Starting service with 'node src/app.js'
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM    throw err;
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM    ^
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  Require stack:
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/routers/dashboard.js
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/app.js
Apr 12 11:42:26 PM      at Function.Module._resolveFilename
```

I tried to update every version to last update still the same issue

Comment: You Are Missing a package in your code check `/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js` nd fixed from ther

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril There is no need to check `BaseClient.js`. The error is thrown because render.com uses an older version of node.js, where `const EventEmitter = require('node:events');` won't work. The question is closed as a duplicate as updating node.js will fix this.